# Why is my copy of Xcode 7.3 giving Seque 'Push' option but not 'Show?

Tags: push, segue, show

Simple question and hopefully a simple answer :-)

Have trawled the net, including SO, but have not found an answer.

So far as I understand it the 'push' option has been replaced by 'show' and is deprecated - but not in my projects!! Is there

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Found the answer.

In 'Interface Builder Document' click the 'Use Size Classes' tick box